# Is there a way of converting a string of 1's and 0's to its binary counterpart, i.e. not ASCII

Tags: python, binary, serial-port

In Python I have learnt that creating ints like `0b01101101` will create a binary literal.

Say I have a string data type of `"01101101"` is there a way to convert this to a binary literal?

The example usage is that I am going to create a data packet slowly building up the byte with relivant pices of data (Setting bits according to variables). Once I have the string, I'll need to write raw binary over a serial connection.

Is it possible to convert the string `"01101101"` to `0b01101101` so it is a binary literal.

Another exammple of my target for this, if it helps. is so I can dynamically create the binary data on the fly without having do do massive bitwise operations, I see it simpler just to make up a string of 1's and 0's as I collate data then convert it to a binary literal. Of course if there is a better way to go about it, improvements would be gladly accepted.

Comment: `0b01101101` represents a binary, but in python it is just a string. If you want to create a number from its binary repr, you can do `int('1011010', 2)`, which will give you the integer that has this binary representation. Then, you can use `bin()` to create the string with the `0b` prepended.

Comment: So a string with `0b` prepended is treated as binary data? So writing over a serial it would be treated as bits and not ASCII?

Comment: In python 2 it would be bytes (so, ASCII, I think), and in python 3 it would be unicode. The prepended `0b` is just a representation, just as `0x` is for hex, so you can do `a = 0b010110`. But the result of `bin()` is a `str` type. If you want to transmit **bits**, then it will do (but probably after cutting off the `0b` with a regex or `.strip('0b')`.

Comment: Either way, using char('10101010') should write the binary value still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note on terminology: a binary literal is a piece of text, normally appearing in source code, so I've shown code that results in the same text, in a string object. A binary literal *is not a number*, but it evaluates to a number in Python code, so I've also shown code to calculate that number. `0b01101101` and `109` are different literals (one binary, one decimal), but when evaluated they give exactly the same result, an integer equal to one hundred and nine.

If you want to write the integer 109 as a single byte over a serial connection, then what you want to write is the single character with code 109, *not* a binary literal.

```
my_string = "01101101"

my_binary_literal = "0b" + my_string
my_string_converted_to_integer = int(my_string, 2)
my_single_character = chr(my_string_converted_to_integer)
assert my_single_character == 'm'
```

Comment: So, in ASCII  the letter 'm' lowercase is 109, so I would have to write that one character over serial?

Comment: If you have a serial protocol that says "next comes a 1-byte integer", and you want that integer to have value 109, then yes write the ASCII character 'm' (although you probably wouldn't write it as `'m'` in your code since that obscures the numeric value from the reader, you'd write it as `chr(109)` or `chr(0b01101101)` or `chr(0x6d)`). The exact details of how to write raw bytes to a serial connection differ between Python 2 and Python 3, so would use the `str` type for this in Python 2 or the `bytes` type in Python 3.

Comment: My spec refers to just what bits are in the byte rather than data types. For example, first two bytes will always be, `10101010`, with a start of 0 and a stop of 1. In this instance, assuming Python 2 would be `chr(0b0101010101)` or split the stop and start bits?, And thanks for letting me know about python 3. is bytes the same procedure?

Comment: @Harvey: the serial driver will handle the start and stop bits for you. There might be some configuration options you can use to control them, but you don't send them in the data.

Comment: Fantastic! I think i have enough here to work it out. Its making sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use argument `base` from string to int conversion:

```
int('01101101', base=2)
# output : 109
# (and 109 in base 10 = 01101101 in base 2)
```

And reverse action, use `bin()` to create the string with a `0b` at the beginning:

```
bin(109)
# output : '0b01101101'
```

Comment: Very good, So I could use something like `bin(int(01101101), 2)` however it  would still be a string? is that actually binary data I can write over a serial or will it be treated like ASCII?

Comment: Rather something like `bin(int('01101101', 2))`. Be careful with parethesis

Answer (score 1):

There is:
First convert it to an int and from there to a binary literal, like so
    `bin(int("01101101", base=2))`

Comment: This is just like doing `str = '0b'+str`, except much longer, isn't it?

Comment: @BusyAnt: well, this code does some validation as well, so it's the same if you don't care about that.

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right, I didn't notice this could throw a `ValueError`. Good point.